# Assigning an array of posix semaphores to shared memory

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, semaphore

I would like to write an array of unnamed semaphores to shared memory so I can access them in forked processes. Here's what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int num_process = atoi(argv[1]);
int i = 0;

int ppid = getpid();
void *addr;

int numsems = 512;
int object_size = numsems * sizeof(sem_t);

printf("declaring semaphores\n");
sem_t *sem[numsems];

//create shared memory and check that it worked
printf("opening shared memory\n");
int shmem_fd = shm_open("/my_shmem", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if(shmem_fd == -1){
    perror("Can't open shmem object");
    exit(-1);
}

//truncate memory object
if(ftruncate(shmem_fd, object_size) == -1){
    perror("failed to resize shmem object");
    exit(-1);
}

addr = mmap(NULL, object_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmem_fd, 0);

if(MAP_FAILED == addr){
    perror("Map failed");
    exit(-1);
}

//store the semaphores at the start
printf("initializing semaphores\n");

for(i = 0; i<numsems; i++){
    sem[i] = addr + i*sizeof(sem_t);
    if(sem_init(sem[i], 1, 0) == -1){
            perror("sem_init failed");
            exit(-1);
    }
}

//create children
while((getpid() == ppid) && (i < num_process)){


    switch(fork()){
    case -1:
    printf("fork %d failed\n", i);
    break;

    case 0:
    //child process
    printf("child created\n");
    child_program( sem, numsems);
    printf("child done\n");
    break;

    default: //parent continues on to create next child
    break;

    }
i++;
}
}
```

Which compiles fine but when I try to run it I get a segmentation fault when it gets to the `sem_t *sem[numsems]` part. I've read elsewhere that you shouldn't create a pointer to semaphores but when I didn't and tried `&sem = addr` I got an error about needing a lvalue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you missed it in chopping down the example but variable i must be set to zero before entering the fork loop otherwise it doesn't run.  Other than that it works for me though I didn't manipulate the semaphores in any way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why not create (and map) the shared memory segment in the parent process, and then open it in the child?

And also, instead of having an array of pointer, why not simply map the whole array, without using pointers:

Parent:

```
sem_t *sem;

shm_open("/my_shmem", O_CREAT | O_RDWR ...);

sem = mmap(NULL, object_size, ...);
```

Child:

```
semt_t *sem;

shm_open("/my_shmem", O_RDWR, 0);

sem = mmap(NULL, object_size, ...);
```

Comment: oops, I had it in my program but when I copied it over I tried clearing things up so I must have lost

Comment: So how would I wait on a certain semaphore? Say the 100th one?

Comment: One advantage of having the shared memory file opened by the parent process and then passed to its children via open descriptor inheritance is that it could be unlinked immediately after it was opened. Thus if the main program crashes, the shared memory block would get deleted automatically when all child processes have finished (either gracefully or not), otherwise it would persist until manually removed.